# Migrating koa v1 to v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2, koa-router

I'm using some module with koa and they only have this documentation which is written in koa v1 not v2. and since I've never used v1 before, I have no idea how to write this in v2.

```
app
  .use(body({
    IncomingForm: form
  }))
  .use(function * () {
    console.log(this.body.user) // => test
    console.log(this.request.files) // or `this.body.files`
    console.log(this.body.files.foo.name) // => README.md
    console.log(this.body.files.foo.path) // => full filepath to where is uploaded
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried runnig it? What failed?

Comment: @Jonasw I'm using koa v2, and my whole koa routers are written in v2 as well. the router never works with other routers that are written in v2. and I just want to write all in v2

Comment: I think replacing function*() with async function (d) , and this with d should do it.

Comment: yeah I get that part since I'm used to v2 but how should I deal with this?
`console.log(this.body.files.foo.path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from Koa v1 to Koa v2 is a pretty simple process. The only reason for the version bump is that it uses `async` functions instead of generators for your middleware.

Example v1 Middleware:

```
app.use(function* (next) {
  yield next
  this.body = 'hello'
})
```

Example v2 Middleware:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  ctx.body = 'hello'
})
```

use `async` functions instead of generators, and accept `ctx` as a parameter instead of using `this`.

Comment: since I'm really used to koa, I get that part. but I have no idea how to deal with `console.log(this.body.files.foo.path) `

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It would just be `ctx.body.files.foo.path` instead of `this.body.files.foo.path`.

Comment: Also, I had an issue in the example v2, I was accidentally still using a genreator instead of an `async` function. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

change the `function *()` to `async function(ctx)` where `ctx` in koa2 is like `this` in koa1

see: http://koajs.com/#context

Comment: what should I do with this ? `console.log(this.body.files.foo.path) `

Comment: Assuming that you have a body parser to parse the body, you would do something like `console.log(ctx.request.body.files.foo.path)`

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/tunnckoCore/koa-better-body. and couldn't figure it out

Comment: I have only ever used `koa-bodyparser` so maybe give that a try

Comment: since `koa-bodyparser` doesn't support multipart-form I obviously needed to use `koa-better-body` but It's quite complicated because all the examples are written in v1

Answer (score 0):

```
app
  .use(body({
    IncomingForm: form
  }))
  .use(function(ctx) {
    console.log(ctx.body.user) // => test
    console.log(ctx.request.files) // or `this.body.files`
    console.log(ctx.body.files.foo.name) // => README.md
    console.log(ctx.body.files.foo.path) // => full filepath to where is uploaded
  })
```